# pyright and imports from shared libraries

Tags: python, pybind11, pyright

Can pyright or any other linter resolve imports from `.so` libraries?
In my case I have a c++ shared library with pybind11 used to generate the python bindings.
I can successfully import and use the `FourierSeries` from the `.so` library

```py
from .c_lib.c_fourier import FourierSeries as FourierSeries_c
```

but at the same time pyright complains that the import cannot be resolved.

> Import ".c_lib.c_fourier" could not be resolved

Any ideas as to how this can be fixed, or at least how to silence this warning?